# How to pass multiple strings into a url in http get?

Tags: http, go

This is my current code:

```
var dek string = "dk"
resp,err := c.Get("https://google."VALUEHERE"")
```

What I want to be able to is pass different strings into my url if I need a bunch of different ones.

So ideally would be something like:

```
resp,err := c.Get("https://google.dk/value1=%v&value2=%v", value1, value2)
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Use `fmt.Sprintf`: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt

Comment: Rather use [`url.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) and [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) so the values get URL-escaped properly.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your current code (the example code you show now is invalid, and won't even compile), and explain the problem you're facing.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes the code does not work i was just trying to illustrate what i needed, i figured it out, but thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fmt.Sprintf(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) to build a string that does not require encoding:

```
hostname := fmt.Sprintf("google.%s", "dk")
// => "google.dk"
```

Use the [`net/url` package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) to build URLs so they are encoded properly:

```
u := &url.URL{Scheme: "https", Host: hostname}
fmt.Println(u)
// => https://google.dk

q := u.Query()
q.Add("value1", "foo")
q.Add("value2", "Hello, World!")
u.RawQuery = q.Encode()
fmt.Println(u)
// => https://google.dk?value1=foo&value2=Hello%2C+World%21

resp, err := c.Get(u.String())
// ...
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!

Comment: @k0ngoz You’re welcome! You can upvote and/or accept this answer if it solves your problem.